# Editorialmanager Elsevier journal submission accepts only a single latex source file

Tags: journal-publishing, journal

On the Editorialmanager website, for second round of review onwards, the journal insists that pdf files are not accepted but only .tex files. The journal site provides options for uploading only the following types of file submissions (see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNKQL.jpg)) :

(a) Latex Source File (b) Figure

Previously, even in later rounds of review, a pdf was acceptable and then I had to separately provide .tex files. The folks behind the scenes at the journal would manually typeset accepted papers and send a pdf back for proofreading. Now, with the provided .tex file, the journal itself builds the pdf automatically at submission stage for onward processing. So, any typesetting errors at this stage means that the submission cannot happen.

At present, my project consists of a `main.tex` that calls (via `\input` command) other files such as `section1.tex`, `section8.tex`, etc. The submission only accepts a singular latex source file (so, multiple `.tex` files seem unacceptable)

Is there any way to convert `main.tex`, `section1.tex`,...,`section8.tex` into one single big consolidated `.tex` file? Also, are the included graphics figures to be uploaded individually as Figure(s) and then the `editorialmanager` website will source these figures automatically?

Thank you.

PS: The journal's latex submission page does not address any of the above questions, hence this post. The journal (under Elsevier) has the following Latex submission help page: https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions

Comment: the page you link to says "Bundle all manuscript source files in a single archive and attach it with item type 'LaTeX source files'. " So you can have a whole folder of input files and images, but submit as a zip archive file not as individual files

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I will have to wait until 2nd round to check this out. In the first round, as indicated in the image in the OP, the manuscript file has a * next to it to indicate it is mandatory. So, the system seems to expect a mandatory pdf file now. So, I cannot submit a zip file alone now, but not a pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) and after some trial and error, here is what worked:

As the site suggests, create a zip file with all `.tex`, `.bib` and `.jpg` files. Upload this zip file as a "Manuscript File". The system seems to unzip this zipped file and loads each individual file. Rename all these files as "Manuscript File"s. The system builds the pdf fine.